# Android Immersive mode in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript-vue

How to make my nativescript-vue android application full screen? 
I have tried https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/ tutorial but it didn't work because it can not find window.getDecorView()

Maybe there is some another way...